# ASP.NET page using only Response.Write

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

Let's say I have some Classic ASP pages that produce all output via Response.Write.

I would like to port these pages over to ASP.NET, but (at least initially) avoid a total rewrite.

How should I set up my ASP.NET project to facilitate this? I assume I would have empty .aspx files and put the VB.NET/C# equivalent of the VBScript code in the codebehind file, and then use Response.Write from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option you describe will work.

Make sure that the `.aspx` pages only have a complete `@page` directive (with `Inherits`, `CodeBehind` and possibly `language` attributes) port the code and use `Response.Write` in the code behind.

You may want to think about porting to a more conventional asp.net application as you go along - common UI elements can be made into user controls and these can then be reused across pages.

Comment: Why only `@page` directive is a condition?

Comment: @abatishchev - When calling an `.aspx` page, it needs to reference the code-behind with the `inherits` attribute. I don't believe the code-behind will execute otherwise.

Comment: So not only `@Page` directive is required (to use code-behind), as you say above, but also `Inherits` and `CodeBegind`/`CodeFile`

Comment: @abatishchev - correct. I meant a full `@page` directive with the minimum attributes for code behind to work.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a tutorial by scott Mitchell about how to convert ASP pages to ASP.NET this way here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973813.aspx .

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an unusual thing to do but the approach you suggest should work.
However I would suggest that the effort involved in converting your vbscript to C#/VB.NET would be better spent in just rewriting as a standard ASP.NET page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

Since **ASP.net MVC** can spit out HTML from the controller you don't even need to build the `.ASPX` page, just the Controllers for your application.

**Two ways to do it:**

```
public ActionResult myAction() {
    Return Content("<html><body>Hello World!</body></html>");
}
```

And, more elegant with better performance (depending on the size of the HTML), but more work: Creating custom `ActionResult` for your pages:

```
public class MyActionResult : ActionResult
{
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        context.HttpContext.Response.Write("<html><body>Hello World!</body></html>");
    }
}
```